# GenericClass<T extends SomeClass> where subclasses of SomeClass should behave differently only acts as SomeClass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I have a couple of problems that are related to each other.

First problem, I have an interface:

```
public interface Copiable<T extends Copiable<T>> 
{
    T getCopy();
}
```

which I use to create deep copies/clones of the implementing classes.

I have a line of classes and another class that is used to contain them, lets say line of classes starts with the class:

```
public class Animal implements Copiable<Animal>
```

and has another class extending it:

```
public class Dog extends Animal
```

In theory (and from what I tested in practice) (Animal object).getCopy() should return an Animal object and (Dog object).getCopy() should return a Dog object.

The container class is also generic and I want it to only contain an Animal or a subclass of it, because I am using Animal (and Copiable) methods. So, I have:

```
public class Container<T extends Animal>
```

and in one of the methods of Container I have something like:

```
public void doSomething(List<? extends T> list)
{
    // ...
    T temp = list.get(i).getCopy(); // Gives an error (1)
    List<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();
    newList.add(list.get(i).getCopy()); // Gives an error (2)
}
```

(1) "error: incompatible types: Animal cannot be converted to T"

(2) "error: no suitable method found for add(Animal)"

Second problem is I am using Container class inside another class, say:

```
public class Zoo
{
    Container<Animal> animals;
    // ...
    void setAnimals(Container<? extends Animal> animals)
    {
        this.animals = animals; // Gives an error (3)
    }
}
```

(3) "error: incompatible types: Container cannot be converted to Container"

and I have subclasses of Zoo that needs to contain subclasses of Animals:

```
public class PettingZoo extends Zoo
{
    // Using the same container in the parent class
    // Container<Animal> animals
    // It needs to contain Dogs
    // and I need to be able to set Container<Dog> to animals
    // and use animals as a list of Dogs in this class
}
```

I would like to learn what is a good way to handle the situation described in the comments above.

I am willing to change my design and I would like to learn the cause of this behaviour and how to fix it.

Comment: ```public interface Copiable<T extends Copiable<T>>``` Why can't you just use ```T```?

Comment: `public class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> implements Copiable<T>{}` and `public class Dog extends Animal<Dog>{}`. This should do the trick

Comment: `<T extends Foo<T>>` is almost always a mistake by someone who doesn't fully understand generics.

Comment: The fact that `Dog` extends `Animal` implies that `Dog` implements `Copiable<Animal>`, not `Copiable<Dog>`.

Comment: There is an existing interface `Cloneable` that serves much the same purpose. Deep vs shallow cloning is an implementation choice. By returning the correct type from `clone()` you can avoid most of the generics stuff presented.

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem That was why I used <T extends Foo>T>> in Copiable interface, because I want each subclass to return its own type. So that is correct right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you probably don't want to use `<T extends Copiable<T>>` as it doesn't really add any value:

```
public interface Copiable<T>{
    T getCopy();
}
```

Secondly you have to add a generic parameter `T` to `Animal`:

```
public class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> implements Copiable<T>{ ... }
```

That way you can define `Dog` as follows:

```
public class Dog extends Animal<Dog>{ ... }
```

And your `Container` like:

```
public class Container<T extends Animal<T>> { ... }
```

At last you have to define your `Zoo` like this:

```
public class Zoo<T extends Animal<T>> { 
    Container<T> animals;

    ...
}
```

Which lets you allow to create a `PettingZoo` only for dogs:

```
public class PettingZoo extends Zoo<Dog> { ... }
```

Comment: I have been trying to make this work. I am still getting all of the errors. What detail I left out was that there is another class extending Dog, say Husky, and I am actually storing Dogs and Huskys in Container where Container has a List<T> where T extends Dog.

My class signatures are as such, [class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> implements Copiable<T>], [class Dog<T extends Dog<T>> extends Animal<T>] and [class Husky extends Dog<Husky>]. I kept the interface Copiable as it is because I need each subclass to return itself and I think that is necessary. Ran out of characters, any idea?